# Try to insert data in the data base using netbeans and mysql database

Tags: java, swing

I have a method in which i am trying to save the values from text boxes into databases but sometime it give me the error

```
 Parameter index out of range (5>number of parameter, which is 1)
```

and some time `java.lang.nullpointerexception`

I don't understand what to do, please help.
Following is the code of the method in which i try to do insert.

```
  private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      try{
        if (y1.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Please enter hostel code","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;}
        else if (y2.getText().equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Please enter hostel location","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;}
        else if (y3.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Please enter hostel name","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;}
       else if (y4.getText().equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Please enter no of rooms","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           return;}
       else if (img.getText().equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Please enter hostel image","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           return;}
                     String room =gender.getSelectedItem().toString();
         pst.setString(5, room);
          Statement stmt;
        stmt= conn.createStatement();
        String sql1="Select HostelName from hostels where HostelName= '" + y3.getText() + "'";
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql1);

        if(rs.next()){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "hostel name already exists","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         y3.setText("");
      y3.requestDefaultFocus();

            return;
                    }

      String sql = "INSERT INTO hostels (`id`, `hloc`, `HostelName`, `RoomNo`, `Capacity`,`image`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

      pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      //for setting values corresponding ?
      pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(y1.getText()));
      pst.setString(2,y2.getText());
      pst.setString(3,y3.getText());
      pst.setInt(4,Integer.parseInt(y4.getText()));
      pst.setString(6,y5.getText());
      pst.setString(7,y6.getText());
      pst.executeUpdate();
      pst.execute();

    refresh();//Update jTable After adding a new record
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Successfully Saved");
        }
 catch(Exception e){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me to get rid of this error? following is the stack trace any help now?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Hostels.saveActionPerformed(Hostels.java:472)
at Hostels.access$700(Hostels.java:28)
at Hostels$8.actionPerformed(Hostels.java:228)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually set any values into your prepared statement. Between `pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);` and `pst.execute();` you need to do `pst.setXXX` to set up all the values corresponding to the `?` in your question.

Keep in mind that the `?` are indexed starting from 1, not from 0.

Comment: i use following for setting values corresponding to the ? by doing this
 `pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(y1.getText()));
  pst.setString(2,y2.getText());
  pst.setString(3,y3.getText());
  pst.setInt(4,Integer.parseInt(y4.getText()));
  pst.setString(6,y5.getText());
  pst.setString(7,y6.getText());
  pst.executeUpdate();` 

but now it give me error
`java.lang.nullpointerexception`

Comment: What line in the code gives the null pointer? Is there any chance that one of the `y.getText()` calls is returning null?

Comment: where is the line `y.getText()` and i set a messagebox to show me error so it didn't give me line number just show the error

Comment: Log the error as well as displaying the message box and you will see the full stack trace. That's very important when trying to track down errors, especially NullPointerException which is one of the most basic and easy to find Exceptions in Java. Print the full stack trace and/or step through the code using a Debugger and you should be able to find it very easily. By `y.getText()` I mean any of the `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, etc.

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand how to log the error give any suggestion how to do it and also no idea of debugging in netbeans just know how to start the debugger but never understand how it works

Comment: This is getting rather long and turning into a conversation so all I can suggest is go read up on these things. At its simplest do ex.printStackTrace() to see the full exception. To Debug click on the grey bar to the left of the code under one of your lines and a red square appears. When you debug the program it will stop at the red square and you can look at variables, step through one at a time, etc. Good luck.

Comment: i also attach the stack trace any kind of help now cause i am getting mad and this error doesn't leave me

Comment: What is line 472 in hostels.java?

Comment: `pst.setInt(1,id);` this is line 472 where `id` is `int id =Integer.parseInt(y1.getText());`

Comment: pst is null then. Are you trying to use it before you created it?

Comment: yes i found it i was using just before the `pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);` and now its working perfectly thanks alot for your kind and generous help thank you

Comment: it says vote require 15 reputation i like the answer